# Infinite Loop in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion

I will preface this with two things. One, I have absolutely no experience with assembly. And two this is for a programming project for my university. I'm trying to solve the Tower of Hanoi problem recursively and I have a basic structure outline and I'm just trying to fill in whats needed as I figure it out. My current problem is that my output is looping infinitely when I have a `syscall` that should be the end message. The problem is when I include it it loops indefinitely, but with it's removal it just goes through what I have and ends like I would have expected it to do with the message there. Here is what I have so far:

```
#############################################
#  $a0 - Origin Peg                         #
#  $a1 - Intermediate Peg                   #
#  $a2 - Destination Peg                    #
#  $a3 - N discs                            #
#  $ra - for return                         #
#############################################

.data

startMsg: .asciiz "Moving n discs"  #will have to change to account for n
moveMsg:  .asciiz "move a disc: "
arrow:    .asciiz " -> "
endMsg:   .asciiz "End of process"

.text
.globl main

 main:
    li $a3, 4           #Four Discs loaded into register a3

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, startMsg    #Load address for first output message
    syscall             #Display message

    jal recHanoi

  li $v0, 4
    la $a0, endMsg      #Load address for last output message
    syscall             #Display end message        

    jr $31

recHanoi:
        subu $sp, $sp, 32
        sw $a0, 0($sp)
        sw $a1, 4($sp)
        sw $a2, 8($sp)

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, arrow   #Load address for first output message
        syscall             #Display message

        #will do recursive calculation stuff here
        #
        #.
        #.
        #.
        #
        j restore

restore:
        lw $a0, 0($sp)
        lw $a1, 4($sp)
        lw $a2, 8($sp)
        addu $sp, $sp, 32

        jr $ra
```

When I remove the three lines after the `jal` there is no infinity. This isn't necessarily keeping from going forward at the moment, but I would like to better understand what exactly is causing this, cause it's not apparent to me currently. Is there a register conflict of some sort that is the root of this or what?

Edit: I should probably mention what the output is. It is the message "End of process" over and over. Which is why this is so alien to me because I would think it would hop into my recHanoi at some point, but it does not.

Edit2: Sorry, its the end message not start

Comment: `$31` is `$ra`. When you did `jal recHanoi`, `$ra` was set to the address of the instruction following the `jal` (i.e. `li $v0, 4`), so you keep jumping back there over and over. You could save the original `$ra` on the stack, but I suggest that you use syscall 10 to exit your program instead.

Comment: @Michael Ah, ignorance on my part. I was unaware they referred to the same register. And I'm honestly unfamiliar with what you mean by syscall 10. Do I use that in the same way I am other syscalls? Is there a special register?

Comment: Refer to any of [the SPIM syscall lists online](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html).